# Error with ImageMin in Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, node-modules, gulp-imagemin, imagemin

When I run the `gulp` command I get the following error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:763:14)
Velibors-MacBook-Pro:gulp3 vel$
```

And when I remove the `imagemin` task from the `gulpfile.js`

```
.pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      interlaced: true,
      svgoPlugins: [{removeUnknownsAndDefaults: false}, {cleanupIDs: false}]
    }))
```

the error is gone and all other tasks execute without errors, but of course, the images are not minified.

I am running on the latest version of OSX Captain.

What could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: Try removing your node_modules folder and install again. See if you get any errors on image-min.

Comment: Might clarify and help to track the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35641655/1064325